# Incorrect or random insert order in entity framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I am looking for a solution that allows you to insert records into the database in the create order. 
So far, I have found information that ef does not support such activities.  
How to get around this?  
I have auto-increment turned on, so I can't give an id for new records (or at least I think so)

The following example writes in db from bottom to top or randomly.

```
var subcategories = new List<Subcategory>()
            {
                new Subcategory { SubcategoryName = "This should be first", CategoryId = 1 },
                new Subcategory { SubcategoryName = "Second", CategoryId = 1 },
                new Subcategory { SubcategoryName = "Third", CategoryId = 2 },
                new Subcategory { SubcategoryName = "Fourth", CategoryId = 2 },
                new Subcategory { SubcategoryName = "LastOne", CategoryId = 3 }
            }

context.Subcategories.AddRange(subcategories);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Database rows have no inherent ordering. If you want a specific order, add a column that allows to later use an `ORDER BY` on it.

Comment: @Alejandro What?! If table has incremental identity column , when executing INSERT statment identities are asigned in the order of the source even if I am inserting multiple rows at once. However, EF does not keep the order in which it feeds INSERT statement in corespondance to the order of the entities in the ChangeTracker, respectively order of Add() calls or order of enumerable in AddRange. Thus entity added later can recieve lower identity than entity added sooner.

Comment: If you control insertion order, an identity column could serve as an ordering column too. But you must control in what order the rows are actually inserted, ie, the order of the `INSERT` instructions or the order in the multiline `INSERT` if you happen to use these.

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking for a solution that allows you to insert records into the database in the right order.

To control the order, call SaveChanges() after adding each entity.  You can wrap all the calls in a transaction to optimize performance.

Comment: and won't that slow down init execution? Will the cost be optimal with e.g. 100 records?

Comment: It's not optimal, but it should be acceptable at that scale.

Comment: Putting everything in a transcation does nothing for performance. It helps with reliability though, in that a failure will cancel the whole batch.